# Set hand tool as default option in Adobe Reader

Tags: windows-xp, adobe-reader

I am using the adobe reader 9.3. I want to set my select option as hand tool by default. But everytime i open a new document the select tool comes by default. I also tried selecting the hand tool by going to tools options and select and zoom and then the hand tool, but still it isn't working for me. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, don't know how to achieve that. But you can select "Use single-key accelerators to access tools" in **strong text**Edit > Prefences > General**strong text**. Then you can choose the hand tool by just typing "H".